# css transform translateX not working in last iOS

Tags: css

I have an animation that slides an image from right to left that worked before, but has stopped working in the latest Safari and iOS.

I don´t understand why?
This is the code.

```
.slideLeft{
    overflow:hidden;
    animation-play-state: paused;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;

    animation-name: slideLeft;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideLeft;  

    animation-duration: 1s; 
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;

    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;     

    visibility: visible !important; 
}

@keyframes slideLeft {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(120%);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideLeft {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(120%);
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
    }
}
```

Any input appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I don't know why but it works for me. Can you share your full code?

Comment: why you use that?     overflow:hidden;
    animation-play-state: paused;
    -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;